# iOS7 - Restore Purchases

Tags: ios, ios7, in-app-purchase

I have the In-App purchase linked to a UUID saved in KeyChain and on the server.

If the user gets a new phone, I don't want him to be able to restore this purchase because now he has the upgraded App on two phones and I'm losing on extra internal costs that the upgrade entails.

Is it okay if I restrict Restore Purchases to true upgrades, that is, to newer devices?

If so, I can detect when a restore is required, and not display it when it isn't required. Does this meet Apple guidelines, or must the Restore Purchases button always be visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consumable purchases are not restorable (at least not via Apple APIs) - so what you choose to do with a consumable purchase is up to you - it can be limited to a single device or linked to an account on your server where you make it available across multiple devices.

Non-consumable purchases are linked to the purchaser's iTunes account and must always be restorable to a user that provides the appropriate account credentials.  This includes on multiple devices, even multiple devices simultaneously (such as an iPhone and an iPad)

Comment: I'm not sure how to classify the In-App purchase. I will post in separate question.